# How to do math inside of a for loop in python?

Tags: python

This is my current code and it is only adding my "z" sum once.

```
increase_rate = int(input("Enter the Percent Daily Increase Rate"))
for i in range(10, 21):
    x = increase_rate/100
    c = 1.5
    y = c * x 
    z = c + y
    print("On Feb", i, z, "million were vaccinated")
```

Result (with input 40)

```
On Feb 10 2.1 million were vaccinated
On Feb 11 2.1 million were vaccinated
On Feb 12 2.1 million were vaccinated
On Feb 13 2.1 million were vaccinated
On Feb 14 2.1 million were vaccinated
On Feb 15 2.1 million were vaccinated
On Feb 16 2.1 million were vaccinated
On Feb 17 2.1 million were vaccinated
On Feb 18 2.1 million were vaccinated
On Feb 19 2.1 million were vaccinated
On Feb 20 2.1 million were vaccinated
```

Result needed:

```
On Feb 10 1.5 million were vaccinated
On Feb 11 2.1 million were vaccinated
On Feb 12 2.94 million were vaccinated
On Feb 13 4.116 million were vaccinated
On Feb 14 5.7624 million were vaccinated
On Feb 15 8.067359999999999 million were vaccinated
On Feb 16 11.294304 million were vaccinated
On Feb 17 15.8120256 million were vaccinated
On Feb 18 22.13683584 million were vaccinated
On Feb 19 30.991570176 million were vaccinated
On Feb 20 43.38819824639999 million were vaccinated
```

How do I get my code to keep going after the 2.1 million while still going in order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the change in your code with few extra variables removed as those were not required:

```
increase_rate = int(input("Enter the Percent Daily Increase Rate"))
c = 1.5
for i in range(10, 21):
    print("On Feb", i, c, "million were vaccinated")
    c = c + c*increase_rate/100
```

Output:

```
Enter the Percent Daily Increase Rate40
On Feb 10 1.5 million were vaccinated
On Feb 11 2.1 million were vaccinated
On Feb 12 2.94 million were vaccinated
On Feb 13 4.116 million were vaccinated
On Feb 14 5.7623999999999995 million were vaccinated
On Feb 15 8.067359999999999 million were vaccinated
On Feb 16 11.294303999999999 million were vaccinated
On Feb 17 15.812025599999998 million were vaccinated
On Feb 18 22.136835839999996 million were vaccinated
On Feb 19 30.991570175999996 million were vaccinated
On Feb 20 43.388198246399995 million were vaccinated
```

The reason for the behavior you re seeing with your code is `c`, `x` and eventually `y` (as it is `c*x`) remains constant and same in every loop, thereby giving same value for `z` (as `z=c+y`) as well. You should have updated `z` in every loop to get the right value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize `z` outside the loop because you will use that value again

```
increase_rate = int(input("Enter the Percent Daily Increase Rate"))
x = increase_rate/100
z = 1.5
for i in range(10, 21):
  print("On Feb", i, z, "million were vaccinated")
  z = z + z*x
```

The output(with input 40):

```
On Feb 10 1.5 million were vaccinated
On Feb 11 2.1 million were vaccinated
On Feb 12 2.9400000000000004 million were vaccinated
On Feb 13 4.1160000000000005 million were vaccinated
On Feb 14 5.762400000000001 million were vaccinated
On Feb 15 8.067360000000003 million were vaccinated
On Feb 16 11.294304000000004 million were vaccinated
On Feb 17 15.812025600000005 million were vaccinated
On Feb 18 22.136835840000007 million were vaccinated
On Feb 19 30.99157017600001 million were vaccinated
On Feb 20 43.388198246400016 million were vaccinated
```